# Hook into "command not found" handler in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualenv

I want to hook into the handler for command not found

```
wim@SDFA100461C:~$ thing
No command 'thing' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tping' from package 'lam-runtime' (universe)
 Command 'thin' from package 'thin' (universe)
thing: command not found
```

I want to override this behaviour with my own script.

Specifically, I want to check if the command exists in the output of `lsvirtualenv -b`, and if so I want to activate that virtualenv.

Where should I start hacking?

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/a/73282/10127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `bash`, its behavior is governed by the shell function `command_not_found_handle` (See `man bash`, under COMMAND EXECUTION).

To see what behavior is defined by that function, you can issue:

```
declare -p -f command_not_found_handle
```

You can change which program is used by redefining the `command_not_found_handle` function.

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it seems the default behavior is defined directly in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
            if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
               /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
               return $?
            elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
               /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
               return $?
            else
               printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
               return 127
            fi
    }
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

### In General

The [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-command-not-found) has a pretty good article:

From bash's man page:

> ... A full search of the directories in PATH is performed only if the
>   command is not found in the hash table. If the search is unsuccessful,
>   the shell searches for a defined shell function named
>   command_not_found_handle. If that function exists, it is invoked with
>   the original command and the original command's arguments as its
>   arguments, and the function's exit status becomes the exit status of
>   the shell. If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error
>   message and returns an exit status of 127.

and

> A quick grep in /etc discovered where it was happening. The function
>   itself is in /etc/bash_command_not_found and that function gets
>   included (if it exists) in your bash session via /etc/bash.bashrc.

### Ubuntu 14.04

Empirical evidence suggests that on an Ubuntu 14.04 installation, the file /etc/bash_command_not_found doesn't exist, however, the correct file is a python script, located at **/usr/lib/command-not-found**

Comment: This set me on the right path, but the actual program was a python script located at `/usr/lib/command-not-found`.  On my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, the file `/etc/bash_command_not_found` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I've added that into my answer for future viewers