# command_not_found_handler not allowing cd command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, shell-script

I have the following code block in the `~/.bashrc` file

```
function command_not_found_handle {
    for dir in $@; do
        path="${path}${dir}/" 
    done
    if [[ -d ${path} ]]; then
        echo "directory exists and and changing to ${path}"
        cd ${path}
    else
        echo "$@ command not found"
    fi
}
```

I am attaching the output also
Here I am trying to apply `cd` command for the command which is not exists

[image: out put for the above code block]
you can see after trying the unusual command it fired `command_not_found_handler` as expected but here `cd` is not worked.
Here `mycode git` is the command which i have to run.This code checks and make the input to directory path `mycode/git` and I am trying to pass this to `cd` but it is not working if it works means the `title` of the Terminal changes to that directory.
To your clarity I am trying the command manually it changes
[image: Manual Entry of cd]
So how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you could use `shopt -s autocd` as explained [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4270/108618).

Comment: Also: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/255414) may be the reason why your `cd` doesn't work.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you got the nice point ....Thanks for the quick response solved the problem

Comment: Glad to know. I have an impression (which may be wrong) that this question and the [previous one](http://superuser.com/q/1099179/432690) target the same root problem that is now solved by `shopt -s autocd`. If I'm right with this, then you have asked wrong questions in the first place. Read [what the XY problem is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the first place is actually i do not know about the `command_not_found_handler`  where as this one  is about the changing directory ........... Any way thanks for the help