# Running *.sh files without typing their .sh extension

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to set up bash so that it executes *any* file with a `.sh` extension, say for example `mycommand.sh`, just by typing `mycommand`, in the same way that in Windows you can execute `mycommand.bat` just by typing `mycommand`?

I already used `chmod +x` and put the directory containing `mycommand.sh` in the `PATH`, so no need to state those things.

An obvious way would be to rename `mycommand.sh` to `mycommand`. I don't want to do this. Some third-party products (e.g. Kafka, and some database systems) provide shell scripts which all have a `.sh` extension and I don't want to be renaming things I don't own.

I'm specifically asking if it's possible to make `.sh` some kind of "known" executable extension, similar to Windows' `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Comment: Why is extension better than shebang? Is it really? Linux way is to use shebang and no extension at all.

Comment: Why not just rename the file and remove the `.sh` extension? Extensions are not relevant in Linux.

Comment: @nKn it's because some third-party products (e.g. Kafka, and some database systems) provide shell scripts which all have a .sh extension and I don't want to be renaming things I don't own.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the files I'm looking at are third-party software from Kafka (also other third-party products do the same) and they _do_ have a shebang, in addition to a .sh extension.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Please clarify _"...I already have... put `mycommand.sh` in the `PATH`"_ - did you add the file's path with the filename to `$PATH`, or did you just add the directory path for the directory containing `mycommand.sh` to `$PATH`?

Comment: @JW0914 the latter: I added the directory path for the directory containing mycommand.sh to $PATH. Sorry for the confusion but that's not important really, I just mentioned the $PATH to confirm that I don't have any issues with bash not finding the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash provides you a way to define your own "command not found" handler:

> If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no slashes, Bash searches each element of `$PATH` for a directory containing an executable file by that name. […] If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined shell function named `command_not_found_handle`. If that function exists, it is invoked in a separate execution environment with the original command and the original command’s arguments as its arguments, and the function’s exit status becomes the exit status of that subshell. If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error message and returns an exit status of `127`.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution))</sup>

This is a basic handler that solves your problem:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
   unset -f command_not_found_handle
   cmmnd="$1".sh
   shift
   exec "$cmmnd" "$@"
}
```

With this function defined, if you try to run `mycommand` and the command is not found, the shell will try `mycommand.sh` with all the command line arguments `mycommand` was supposed to get.

Notes:

- Other shells may provide similar functionality.
- `unset` prevents the handler from triggering itself again in case the new command is not found either.
- You may have some handler already defined. E.g. in Debian the `command-not-found` package relies on its handler. You will lose it if you simply define your own. To keep the old functionality you need to mimic (or reinstate) the old handler and run its code after the new command is not found (but make sure it effectively works as if it got the original command, i.e. `mycommand`, not `mycommand.sh`). The old handler may look like in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1099222/432690).

Comment: works like a charm... but Linux should implement a "PATHEXT" environment variable "á lá Windoze..." !!! it is very convenient... as I usually put there my .py and other scripts I want the shell to execute just typing the name... ;-)

Comment: @ZEE I disagree. The right thing is not to leak the implementation details to the filename. If you create a tool you want to call as `foo` then name it `foo`, regardless of the desired interpreter. Shebang is where the interpreter is specified. PATHEXT in Windows is convenient only because extensions matter in Windows. It solves a problem that does not exist in Linux. If you choose to bring the problem to Linux by naming your tool `something.py` then you obviously want to bring the solution along. The right thing is not to bring the problem to Linux in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it helped me when I had this problem and I've since made improvements to the chosen answer which I think are worth sharing. My implementation works on all executable types, not just .sh, and it doesn't botch the error message when a command isn't found:

```bash
command_not_found_handle() {
    unset -f command_not_found_handle
    found=false

    # Iterate over possible autocompletions.
    while IFS='' read -r cmmnd; do
        # If the only thing that was autocompleted was the extension, execute it,
        # but outside the loop because STDIN is redirected inside here.
        if [[ "$cmmnd" == "$1".* ]]; then
            found=true
            break
        fi
    done < <(compgen -c -- "$1") # Generate possible autocompletions for the command.

    $found && exec -- "$cmmnd" "${@:2}"
    echo "bash: '$1': command not found" >&2
    return 127
}
```