# Running python script without typing its `.py` extension

Tags: macos, command-line, python, zsh, macos-catalina

I'm using Zsh on MacOS Catalina.

I was reading *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* and in it the author runs `mapIt.py` simply by typing `mapit` into the terminal.

In order to do this I added a shebang to the top of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I also marked it with `chmod +x script.py` and added the directory to my `PATH`.

However in order to run it, I need to type `script.py`. Typing just `script` doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [I found it online](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/). This fragment

> ```
> C:\> mapit 870 Valencia St, San Francisco, CA 94110
> ```

(namely `C:\>`) and other details indicate the author uses Windows. In Windows there are ways to run files of certain extensions by typing their names without extensions. The author most likely has enabled the feature for `.py`. Compare this: **[Making Python scripts run on Windows without specifying `.py` extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9037346/10765659)**.

In Unix/Linux `.py` in `script.py` is just a part of the name. There is no concept of extension (other than the concept in user's mind maybe).

So just name the script `script` instead of `script.py`. If you want to be able to run the same script regardless if you type `script.py` or `script`, then place the script under one name and make a symlink from the other name to the actual script.

Note (at least in Linux) there is `script(1)` utility. Depending on your `PATH` a command `script` will run the script or the utility (if installed).

---

Another approach is to make your shell try to run `foo.py` if `foo` resulted in `command not found` (for any `foo`). See this general question:

- **[How to define a function that handles `command not found`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333241/108618)**

and these two answers as examples (note they are for Bash):

- **[Running `*.sh` files without typing their `.sh` extension](https://superuser.com/a/1504032/432690)**
- **[Is there a Unix equivalent of the Windows environment variable `PATHEXT`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280602/108618)**

In Zsh the function is named [`command_not_found_handler`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#Command-Execution). Build your solution by porting one of the examples to Zsh.

Comment: Would the Python script still be able to execute if it didn't have the .py extension?

Comment: @alibiineed If the permissions and the shebang are right then it should. Why don't you just try?