# Bash/Zsh: Catching all commands that start with a `/`

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, interactive

Is there a way to get this example `catchall` function to be called whenever any command starts with the `/` character in an interactive shell (instead of searching in `$PATH` and executing something else, etc)?

For example, I would want

```
/arg1 arg2 arg3
```

to call

```
function catchall() {
    /* $1 == "arg1"
       $2 == "arg2"
       $3 == "arg3" */
    ...
}
```

Comment: (1) Should it work in an interactive shell? or in a script? Both? (2) Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. What *actual problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Edited to include "interactive shell". There is no XY problem here. The actual problem I am trying to solve is a function call can generalize commands by a prefix. The `/` is an example. The `catchall` function is also only an example.

Comment: (3) Do you want `catchall` to run instead of the typed command? or along? (before or after?).

Comment: That's a good clarification. I mean instead of the typed command.

Comment: I think it can be done in zsh using the _precmd_ feature. See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580675/zsh-preexec-command-modification) question. However, I would consider it highly disturbing and error prone, if under the hood a different command is executed than the one I have entered.

Answer (score 0):

A limited (imperfect) solution for Bash:

```bash
shopt -s extdebug

_generic() {
   case "$BASH_COMMAND" in
      /* )
         eval "_specific $BASH_COMMAND"
         return 1
      ;;
   esac
}

_specific() {
   printf "Got arguments: "
   printf '<%s> ' "$@"
   printf '\n'
   printf 'The command was: %s\n' "$BASH_COMMAND"
}

trap '_generic' DEBUG
```

Based upon:

- [Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?](https://superuser.com/q/175799/432690)
- [Cancel command in bash `DEBUG` trap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/663094/108618)

Example usage:

```bash
$ /foo "a         b" /dev/[nf]ul* ; /bar <(cat)
Got arguments: </foo> <a         b> </dev/full> </dev/null> 
The command was: /foo "a         b" /dev/[nf]ul*
Got arguments: </bar> </dev/fd/63> 
The command was: /bar <(cat)
$
```

Notes:

- I don't know Zsh. This answer is for Bash.
- [`eval` can be evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). AFAIK `eval`uating `$BASH_COMMAND` is not wrong because `$BASH_COMMAND` is equivalent to the string you typed and it hasn't been evaluated yet. Our `eval` does what the shell would normally do anyway.
- Still `$BASH_COMMAND` is not the full string you typed. E.g. `/foo; /bar` will call `_generic` (and thus `_specific`) *separately* for `/foo` and `/bar`. This is how the `DEBUG` trap works. In the context of your question this seems fortunate.
- `_generic` operates on `$BASH_COMMAND` with is a string. `_specific` works with an array of arguments from evaluation of `$BASH_COMMAND`, nevertheless `$BASH_COMMAND` is still available. In principle you should use the array (or elements of it), i.e. `"$@"` (or `"$1"`, `"$2"`, …). I can imagine `$BASH_COMMAND` may be used for some wizardry though.
- You could use `eval "_specific ${BASH_COMMAND#/}"` instead of `eval "_specific $BASH_COMMAND"` to strip the leading `/` when calling `_specific`. Note if you do this and if the command is `/ whatever …` then the first argument to `_specific` will be `whatever`, not an empty string. For this reason you may want to strip the leading `/` only inside `_specific` (e.g. `argument1="${1#/}"`).
- Expanding the code to cover more prefixes is simple: build any number of specific functions and add more cases for `case`.
- **The core of the solution is the `DEBUG` trap which is for debugging and as such it tries not to disturb stdin, stdout or the exit status.** Our `_specific` cannot fully replace `/foo` in cases like `<input /foo >output`, `/foo | wc -c` or `/foo || whatever`. A solution with [`command_not_found_handle`](https://superuser.com/a/1504032/432690) would be better in these matters, but it would only kick in if `/foo` wasn't a valid command; so it would probably work for `/arg1` or `/bin/nonexistent`, but not for `/bin/echo`. (Compare this answer: [How do I create a command prefix for bash with an alias?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697666/108618))