# Run bash scripts without typing the file extension the right way

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, script

I'm on Windows 10 and decided to transition from cmd to Git Bash. Say I have a script `foo.sh`, I'd like to be able to run it with the command `foo` and not `foo.sh`. I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1504032/1262765), which works in some cases but not all:

1. It only works if the script is in PATH. If it's just a script in my current directory, all the following forms don't work: `foo`, `./foo`, `foo.sh`. The only way that works is `./foo.sh` (so I still have to type the extension). I would expect `./foo` to work, I don't know why it doesn't. It's as if the command not found handler doesn't even run in this case.
2. I discovered that `cd` in a bash script doesn't work, you have to source the script like so: `. foo.sh`. Again, I'd like to be able to run `. foo`.
3. It doesn't work in bash scripts that call other bash scripts.

So my question is how do I get rid of the need to type .sh **everywhere**, not just under specific circumstances.

EDIT: since I was asked, the output for `assoc .sh` on my machine is:

> .sh=sh_auto_file

And the output for `ftype sh_auto_file` is:

> sh_auto_file="C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --no-cd "%L" %*

Comment: Just [name the script `foo`](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski He wants to mimic Windows executable behavior from a Bash shell prompt.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and you may be able to find a workaround. But this isn't how it's done in Linux. Executables are determined by a bit flag in the filesystem and the program association is done either by a file header, in the case of a binary file, or a shebang for a text file. If you want to familiarize yourself with a Unix shell and filesystem characteristics, I would recommend that your learn how this is traditionally done.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a couple steps.

- Add `.sh` to the PATHEXT environment variable
- Define an FTYPE for .sh `ftype bash.File=c:\somepath\bash.exe "%1" %*`
- Define an assoc for .sh `assoc .sh=bash.File`

Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037346/making-python-scripts-run-on-windows-without-specifying-py-extension

Comment: assoc and ftype were already set up, I think they're just for running scripts with a double click. Adding .sh PATHEXT works for cmd but not for bash.

Comment: can you add the details to your question? (petinent output of assoc, ftype and Set)

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Bash requires an explicit filename, that's why you needed to perform such an obtuse workaround. It's also case sensitive, unless special consideration is being taken for a Windows environment.

What you're trying to do is shoehorn a Windows shorthand onto a Unix shell where it never existed. Outside of your trusted use case, it is also a security risk, for example, foo.exe could be dropped into the PATH and take priority.

My workaround for this was to adopt a habit of naming all executable shell scripts without the extension and all non-executable scripts (such as those that are includes or dependencies) with an extension. This has the added benefit of being easier to tab complete when there are files of similar, completable names, as it is already explicit without the extension.

Comment: Getting rid of the file extension has some unwanted side effects. Text editors may fail to recognize the file type, and more importantly I will no longer be able to run scripts by double clicking them like an exe.

Comment: You are correct. It's not a perfect workaround, but it's how I've decided to do it. The extension is also somewhat arbitrary anyways, since you have to make assumptions as to *which* shell is to be used. The correct way to handle this is with a shebang, at which point the extension becomes meaningless. Some editors for Windows may be able to read the shebang to determine which syntax highlighter to use, but there is no facility to bootstrap execution in this way natively without a file extension.

Comment: Symlinking to the extensioned file is the more common approach. Bash doesn't require an explicit filename. It's windows

Comment: nvm, it's the other way around. Still, symlinks are a nice alternative to moving files

Answer (score 0):

As @uSlacr [points out](https://superuser.com/a/1731125), there are three steps.

You may run this `.BAT` file in an administrative command prompt to do them

```
:: Make .sh and .bash files executable without extension

:: Append .sh to PATHEXT
setx PATHEXT "%PATHEXT%;.SH;.BASH" /M
:: Define an FTYPE
FTYPE bash.File="C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe" "%%1" %%*
:: Define ASSOC for that FTYPE
ASSOC .sh=bash.File
ASSOC .bash=bash.File
```

The path to bash varies by how you installed git-for-windos. You can generate the `.bat` file in bash using

```bash
#!/bin/bash

bash_location="$(git --exec-path |
  sed 's@\(.*Git/\).*@\1bin/bash.exe@')"

printf '%s' ':: Make .sh and .bash files executable without extension

:: Append .sh to PATHEXT
setx PATHEXT "%PATHEXT%;.SH;.BASH" /M
:: Define an FTYPE
FTYPE bash.File="'"$bash_location"'" "%%1" %%*
:: Define ASSOC for that FTYPE
ASSOC .sh=bash.File
ASSOC .bash=bash.File
' > exec-sh-ext.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's just a matter of

1. making sure your script is a Bash script, for which its first line should be `#!/bin/bash`
2. removing the extension altogether, for example `mv ./script1.sh ./script1`
3. making the file executable, for example `chmod 777 ./script1`
4. (optionally) including the dir of your script in the PATH, for example `export PATH="$HOME/my-scripts:$PATH"`

If you do all 4 steps, then you can run your script with `script1` from wherever.