# Getting rid of "command not found..."

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, delay

When I mistype command in terminal I got this error:

`bash: XX: command not found...`

After that, I have to wait or use keyboard interrupt before I can use prompt again.
Sometimes shell offers me to install some command and that's quite annoying.

Is there any way to get rid of this delay?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay is caused by a custom [command-not-found handler](https://superuser.com/questions/787424/hook-into-command-not-found-handler-in-ubuntu) added by your distribution. It is usually added somewhere in the system-wide `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.

The handler is just a shell function with a specific name, so you can also disable or override it via **~/.bashrc** (e.g. if you don't want to change the system-wide config).

If the distro's handler is being too slow, then you can simply remove (`unset -f`) the function and return to bash's standard behavior:

```
unset -f command_not_found_handle
```

On the other hand, if you don't like the *message*, then you can define your own version of the handler (again via ~/.bashrc):

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    echo "I don't know what '$1' is." >&2
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, anyway what `>&2` in your echo means?

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to uninstall the package that provides the executable `pk-command-not-found` -- on my Rocky Linux 9 the `command_not_found_handle` looks like this:

```
command_not_found_handle () 
    [[ ! -x '/usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found' ]] && runcnf=0;
        '/usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found' "$@";
            printf 'bash: %scommand not found\n' "${1:+$1: }" 1>&2;
```

So you can see that it's dependent on that `/usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found` executable.

On a Red Hat-like system, you can do this to find out what package it is and uninstall it:

```
# rpm -qf /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found
PackageKit-command-not-found-1.2.4-2.el9.x86_64
# dnf remove PackageKit-command-not-found
```

This changes it system-wide, all users would be affected.

*Oh, and `2>&1` is just bash file handle redirection. It literally means "send my stderr to the same thing as stdout".*